# jquery plugin architecture

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Hello I am creating an app with some Heavy Javascript functionality I have questions on how to architect it.

I have a Jquery plugin A which communicates with plugin B. there are functions in plugin B which can be called when an event occurs in plugin A. this is a basic setup.

but if users want they can use plugin C instead of plugin B and override default behavior of the plugin B. but cannot change the function name or anything in plugin A which by default calls plugin B.

Is there any way that I can achieve this easily? and what architecture should I follow. 
I want an event to be raised when plugin B initializes and then may be I can override it by a function in plugin C.

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

consider the following example.

I have subscribed for an event

```
  A.subscribe(Event, function(topic, data) {
            $.defaultfunction(Event, data, Value);
          });
```

by default it calls a function which is in plugin B. and plugin B has the defaultfunction.

Now i need a way to override the default behaviour which is in defaultfunction in plugin B with another function in another plugin C.

I hope My question is clear.

Comment: you should be more speciffic. some code samples are welcomed

Comment: I have added some code. let me know if its clear

Answer (score 3):

Instead of having plugin A call plugin B, have plugin A trigger an event that both plugin B and C are listening for. This allows plugin A to broadcast it's event to whichever of B or C are being used.

Comment: the issue is plugin B will always be listening to plugin A events. plugin A and plugin B are like default plugins which cannot be modified. I want to create another plugin C which is optional but when present will override plugin B behaviour

Comment: if you can't modify plugin B, how is plugin C overriding it? i don't see how that is an issue.

Comment: I am creating both of them but this will be deployed and given access to external users who cannot modify either plugin A or B I need to architect in such a way that plugin B behavior can be overriden by another custom plugin

Comment: Right. so create plugin A in such a way that it does not depend on Plugin B. plugin B should react to plugin A triggering an event. Then, if someone wants to instead use plugin C, they simply include plugin C and have it react to plugin A's events. I'll setup a fiddle.

Comment: Here's an example. http://jsfiddle.net/7yvuq/ In this case, pluginB and pluginC simply co-exist. If the developer wanted to override it, he would simply either not include pluginB, or override it with `$.fn.pluginB = function(){ return this; };`

Comment: here it is with pluginB overridden: http://jsfiddle.net/7yvuq/1/